# Pygame: How do I fix the issue of randomly generated platforms on PyGame moving in the wrong direction in the wrong section of the screen?

Tags: python, pygame

so I have been following some guides, and taking some of my own initiative, but I've now gotten stuck. I am at a point where platforms are being generated randomly (yay) and are appearing on the screen (double yay), but are going from the bottom of the screen to the top instead of right to left which I would like. I am finding it difficult to understand how to modify this.

I have (foolishly) tried changing a variable name. 
I tried changing what's within randint and the append parts. But there's not much I want to tinker around with like the "pos", for example, as I am just not too sure what's even going on with it.

```
# For the program, it was necessary to import the following.
import pygame, sys, random
import pygame.locals as GAME_GLOBALS
import pygame.event as GAME_EVENTS
import pygame.time as GAME_TIME

pygame.init() # To initialise the program, we need this command. Else nothing will get started.

StartImage = pygame.image.load("Assets/Start-Screen.png")
GameOverImage = pygame.image.load("Assets/Game-Over-Screen.png")

# Window details are here
windowWidth = 1000
windowHeight = 400

surface = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth, windowHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('GAME NAME HERE')

oneDown = False

gameStarted = False
gameEnded = False

gamePlatforms = []
platformSpeed = 3
platformDelay = 4000
lastPlatform = 0


gameBeganAt = 0
timer = 0

player = {
    "x": 10,
    "y": 200,
    "height": 25,
    "width": 10,
    "vy": 5
}


def drawingPlayer():
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (248, 255, 6), (player["x"], player["y"], player["width"], player["height"]))


def movingPlayer():
    pressedKey = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressedKey[pygame.K_UP]:
        player["y"] -= 5
    elif pressedKey[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        player["y"] += 5


def creatingPlatform():
    global lastPlatform, platformDelay
    platformY = windowWidth
    gapPosition = random.randint(0, windowWidth - 100)
    gamePlatforms.append({"pos": [0, platformY], "gap": gapPosition})
    lastPlatform = GAME_TIME.get_ticks()

def movingPlatform():
    for idx, platform in enumerate(gamePlatforms):
        platform["pos"][1] -= platformSpeed
        if platform["pos"][1] < -10:
            gamePlatforms.pop(idx)

def drawingPlatform():
    global platform
    for platform in gamePlatforms:
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, (214, 200, 253), (platform["gap"], platform["pos"][1], 40, 10))


def gameOver():
    global gameStarted, gameEnded, platformSpeed

    platformSpeed = 0
    gameStarted = False
    gameEnded = True


def quitGame():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()


def gameStart():
    global gameStarted
    gameStarted = True


while True:
    surface.fill((95, 199, 250))
    pressedKey = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in GAME_EVENTS.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # Event key for space should initiate sound toggle
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                oneDown = True
                gameStart()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                oneDown = False
                #KEYUP for the space bar
        if event.type == GAME_GLOBALS.QUIT:
            quitGame()

    if gameStarted is True:
        drawingPlayer()
        movingPlayer()
        creatingPlatform()
        movingPlatform()
        drawingPlatform()

    elif gameEnded is True:
        surface.blit(GameOverImage, (0, 0))

    else:
        surface.blit(StartImage, (0, 0))



    pygame.display.update()
```

Expected result: Platforms approaching the yellow rectangle from the right side of the screen to the left, also the rectangle being tall instead of wide.

Actual result: Platforms coming from the bottom of the screen to the top, and the platforms being wide. But I can probably fix the latter, I just want to work on the direction first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so here were the changes I made:
In `creatingPlatform()` I created a variable to hold the vertical position of the platforms.  I also renamed your `platformY` to `platformX`, because it's a random x-position, not a random y-position.
I used the new vertical position as part of the "pos" attribute of the platform, and put them in the conventional (x, y) ordering. Here's the code for the modified function:

```
def creatingPlatform():
    global lastPlatform, platformDelay
    platformX = windowWidth
    gapPosition = random.randint(0, windowWidth - 100)
    verticalPosition = random.randint(0, windowHeight)
    gamePlatforms.append({"pos": [platformX, verticalPosition], "gap": gapPosition})
    lastPlatform = GAME_TIME.get_ticks()
```

Next, I had to modify `movingPlatform()` so that it updated the x-position, and not the y-position.  That just involved changing the index of `platform["pos"]` from 1 to 0:

```
def movingPlatform():
    for idx, platform in enumerate(gamePlatforms):
        platform["pos"][0] -= platformSpeed
        if platform["pos"][0] < -10:
            gamePlatforms.pop(idx)
```

Lastly, I just passed the platform positions into the draw function:

```
def drawingPlatform():
    global platform
    for platform in gamePlatforms:
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, (214, 200, 253), (platform["pos"][0], platform["pos"][1], 40, 10))
```

This produced platforms moving right-to-left, and they are also wide and not tall!

Comment: Hello @DatHydroGuy thank you. So I managed to get that to work, and I rotated the platform so it could be vertical instead of horizontal when it comes towards my player. However, I'm struggling to make them spaced out. They come in clumps, and I'm hoping to create a system where the space between the arriving platforms are constant. Is there a solution for this? ^^

Comment: Hi @Lucinda You're welcome - glad I could help, and happy to hear that you've progressed things yourself.  I'm sure we can try to sort out the platform spacing issue, but it would be more appropriate to StackOverflow rules (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275908/more-than-one-question-per-post) if you could post it as a new question (along with your updated code).

Comment: Sorry about that. Well, I've posted a new question now so people can look at it!